# Problem moving whole html-page down! margin-top to html element doesn't work on all pages

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, margin

i have a strange css, JS problem. My chrome-extension should move the hole website some pixels down, so i can display a toolbar on top of it.

This works for most pages, but doesn't work for a few. And i can't find out what's the problem. The code for moving the page down is really simple. Just this line, which adds a margin-top to the html-element:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.marginTop = '36px !important';
```

It's easiest explained and seen if you install the addon and browse to www(dot)interspar(dot)at (here it works) and to www(dot)weinwelt(dot)at (here it doesn't work). The addon is found here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pilobbegphefikcgjpajnneiiahhejam

Please don't consider this as spam, as this addon is only useful for german speaking people and i think there aren't many around here ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work on that site because its whole content is positioned absolutely (look at `<div class="parent">`). You need to loop through the whole DOM looking for absolutely positioned elements that have `top` property and increase its value accordingly as well.

That's only a tip of the iceberg though, as some sites would be adding absolutely positioned elements to the page dynamically, so you would need to listen to dom changes (`DOMSubtreeModified` event) as well and do all repositioning again.

Answer (score 2):

Try it on the BODY instead;

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.marginTop = '36px !important';
```

[HTML tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_html.asp) can't have a margin on it.

Comment: hi @kon, this doesn't solve the problem. Adding the margin to the html-tag works already (for most of the pages) only a few pages make problems. Maybe the chrome browser is tolerant.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just missing something specific to Chrome add-ons (or web development in general), but you can NOT have margins applied to your HTML tag - it's not valid HTML, so you can't count on it working consistently in all browsers.

Comment: it doesn't need to work in all browsers. only in chrome ;) i'm aware now, that this wasn't valid HTML and i changed it as soon as you mentioned it. But it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score -3):

According to following link "!important" is only supported by safari.

http://hungred.com/how-to/jquery-javascript-css-important/

Comment: You should take a look at a few other articles!